# Record online streaming (Radio) while playing the streaming

Tags: android, audio, stream, media-player

I am trying to record the online streaming (Radio station) while station plays in MediaPlayer.

As android does not provide any way to record audio from MUSIC source (as we did for MIC, VOICE_UPLINK, etc).

So I have created a local web server in my app, and gives that local url to MediaPlayer to play station streaming.

In my local web service I did following:

1. Open URL connection from original stream url.
2. Create read buffer. Original stream url (bitrate / 8) E.g. bitrate = 128 kbps so buffer size will be ((128 / 8) * 1024) i.e. 16 KBps.
3. Get input stream, and read bytes from stream and write to output stream of web service.

MediaPlayer plays streaming without any problem. But when I record the audio then starting point of recording is wrong (E.g If I record audio from 5:15 minutes then recording starts from 5:20 minutes, 5 seconds audio data missed) and this difference increased as playing time increases.

In short: I have facing the problem fast downloading speed and slow playing speed by MediaPlayer.

Is my calculation is wrong to create read buffer size? how can I match the downloading and playing speed of MediaPlayer?

Comment: Some online radio protocols have metadata embedded in the streams. Are you taking that into account?

Comment: @Michael what metadata are you referring (bitrate, content-Type) or something else.

Comment: For shoutcast streams you can get information like the title of the song when the song on the station changes (see http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html).